# Deduce template parameter through std:is_base_of

Tags: c++11, templates, shared-ptr

Consider the following example:

```cpp
#include <memory>

template<class T>
class RefSP {
private:
    std::shared_ptr<T> p;
public:
    template<class A>
    RefSP(A&& v) : p(std::forward<A>(p)) {}
};

template <
        class T,
        class U,
        typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<std::shared_ptr<U>, T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
inline RefSP<U>*
make_ref_sp(T&& p)
{
    return new RefSP<U>(std::forward<T>(p));
}

int main()
{
    auto sp = std::make_shared<int>(42);
    auto x = make_ref_sp(sp);
}
```

I get compilation error

```
 In function 'int main()':
25:28: error: no matching function for call to 'make_ref_sp(std::shared_ptr<int>&)'
25:28: note: candidate is:
17:1: note: template<class T, class U, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<std::shared_ptr<_Tp2>, T>::value>::type* <anonymous> > RefSP<U> make_ref_sp(T&&)
17:1: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
25:28: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'U'
```

The question is, how can I fix the code so that `U` will be inferred given that `T` is `std::shared_ptr<U>` while preserving move-semantics.

Comment: What about `if constexpr (std::is_specialization_v<T, std::shared_ptr>) {` (or the like) ?

Comment: 1) Replace U with something like `std::remove_cvref_t<T>`. 2) Are you trying to create `std::shared_ptr<std::shared_ptr<int>>`? Why? `RefSP` also needs fixing.

Comment: So you want `U` to be `int` when `T` is `std::shared_ptr<int>`? Then what's the meaning of `std::is_base_of`? It'll always be `true`.

Comment: In constructor of `RefSP` do `RefSP(A&& v) : p(std::forward<A>(v))` and also try `auto x = make_ref_sp(std::move(sp))`

Comment: To elaborate more on the main question: you don't deduce U from T, instead you transform T to what you want U to be. You can't just ask a compiler to deduce U in generic way - what if you write your types and templates in a way that  deducing U is equivalent to e.g. proving Ferma theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::is_base_of` is a trait for inheritance...

You would need special trait for that:

```
template <typename> struct is_shared_ptr : std::false_type {};
template <typename T> struct is_shared_ptr<std::shared_ptr<T>> : std::true_type
{
    // Possibly add information here
    // using element_type = T;
};

template <
        class T,
        typename std::enable_if<is_shared_ptr<typename std::decay<T>::type>::value, int>::type = 0>
RefSP<typename std::decay<T>::type::element_type>
make_ref_sp(T&& p)
{
    return RefSP<U>(std::forward<T>(p));
}
```

I would simply do:

```
#include <memory>

template <class T>
class RefSP {
private:
    std::shared_ptr<T> p;
public:
    explicit RefSP(std::shared_ptr<T>&& v) : p(std::move(v)) {}
};

template <class T>
RefSP<T> make_ref_sp(std::shared_ptr<T>&& p)
{
    return RefSP<T>(std::move(p));
}

int main()
{
    auto sp = std::make_shared<int>(42);
    auto x = make_ref_sp(std::move(sp));
}
```

If you want to allow implicit copy, you might add corresponding overloads:

```
template <class T>
RefSP<T>::RefSP(const std::shared_ptr<T>& v) : p(v) {}

template <class T>
RefSP<T> make_ref_sp(const std::shared_ptr<T>& p)
{
    return RefSP<T>(p);
}
```

And if you don't want to write overload and let user choose between (implicit) copy and move, replace all overloads by:

```
template <class T>
RefSP<T>::RefSP(std::shared_ptr<T> v) : p(std::move(v)) {}

template <class T>
RefSP<T> make_ref_sp(std::shared_ptr<T> p)
{
    return RefSP<T>(std::move(p));
}
```